# Jquery gantt plugin shows one day earlier

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timezone, gantt-chart

I am using the [jQuery.ganttView plugin](https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView). I works very well, but it has a problem with UTC-N timezones, as UTC-07.00 for example. Hence, it shows one day earlier.

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903042/jquery-gantt-date-issues), but it does not provide a solution for me.

How to solve this?